# JPA setup with WIldfly24 throws NullPointerException

Tags: jpa, jboss

After initializing JPA for a JSF project within the pox.xml I get this error code:

```
11:38:38,261 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:358)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:207)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:40)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.init(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:849)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeFacelets(ApplicationAssociate.java:342)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getCompiler(ApplicationAssociate.java:420)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:217)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:342)
    ... 22 more

11:38:38,263 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:286)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:358)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:40)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.init(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:849)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeFacelets(ApplicationAssociate.java:342)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getCompiler(ApplicationAssociate.java:420)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:217)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:342)
    ... 22 more

11:38:38,266 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
11:38:38,266 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
11:38:38,267 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
11:38:38,304 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT (runtime-name: Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war) in 36ms
[2021-09-16 11:38:38,340] Artifact Test:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2021-09-16 11:38:38,340] Artifact Test:war exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

Even after removing the dependencies and the META-INF + persistence.xml the same error will occur. Before initializing the JPA there was no problem. I dont think this error is because of JPA. I will post the relevant sourcecode below:

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
  <persistence-unit name="default">
      <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/primeleague" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.true</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thanks for helping in the first place.

Comment: Hey Lara, It's maybe irrelevant, but in your persistence.xml file, you have this line, `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />` and so far I know, that's for configuring in hibernate and not JPA. Maybe it could be an start.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I forgot,taht you can't answer comments, cause you are a new contributor. So I'm writing it again as an answer, so you can reply back.

It's maybe irrelevant, but in your persistence.xml file, you have this line,  and so far I know, that's for configuring in hibernate and not JPA. Maybe it could be an start.